# How to limit the volume of the buttons (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, audio

**How to limit the volume of the buttons (Swift)**

I have code to add sound to the buttons.

How can I make it so that, regardless of the sound state of the device, the volume of the key is always on the same level?

```
var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

@IBAction func Sound(_ sender: UIButton) {
    guard UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "SwitchState2") else { return }
    audioPlayer.play()
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let music = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "PBOING1", ofType: "WAV")
    do {
        audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: music! ))
    }
    catch{
        print(error)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting the volume: `audioplayer.volume = 0.0 to 1.0`

You can read more about `AVAudioPlayer` here :

> https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudioplayer/1389330-volume